# How to read from console in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, input, console

How do I read a string or character from MATLAB console (command window)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See [Request input](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/input.html) for the complete reference

```
reply = input('Do you want more? Y/N [Y]: ', 's');
if isempty(reply)
    reply = 'Y';
end
```